# react-select: go to link from the opened menu

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select, with the async option.
Actually when you do a search and click on one of the results, it is displayed in the searchbar and only if I click again on the result in the searchbar, it fires the action.
Is it possible to fire the action when clicking, for the very first time, on the single result from the opened search menu? Like Google search I mean.

Thx